# Errores npm relacionados a package.json: npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Este es el error que me esta dando al tratar de instalar npm.

> npm ERR! code EJOSNPARSE npm ERR! file
> C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Escritorio\my-world-master\package.json npm
> ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected
> end of JSON input while parsing near '...rver": "^2.5.4" npm ERR!
> JSON.parse   }, npm ERR! JSON.parse '
>
> npm ERR!       JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data. npm ERR!
> JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\andre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\logs\2020-07-12T22_29_27_626Z-debug.log

```
  {
     "name": "my world master",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "mi primer proyecto de node.js",
     "main": "index.html",
     "scripts": {
     "dev":"lite-server"
  },
     "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "my world master"
  },
     "author": "Josue Andres",
     "license": "ISC",
     "devDependencies": {
     "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  },
```

Necesito ayuda, sin poder solucionar esta acción no puedo seguir con mi proyecto, es mi primera ves programando

Comment: Tu JSON es invalido y contiene errores, seguramente entraste en el y lo modificaste o realizaste una accion que no se llego a terminar mediante la consola, te aconsejo apuntar que cosas has instalado desde el package.json y hacer una lista aparte, para posteriormente eliminar el package.json y crear uno nuevo usando `npm init`. luego cuando ya se haya generado tu json simplemente te encargarias de volver a instalar todo lo que tenias, la verdad es que sin que pongas el contenido de tu `package.json` en la pregunta nos lo pones bastante dificil.

Comment: Hola Riven. Gracias, voy a intentar borrarlo para volver a crear uno nuevo. Listo, este seria el contenido de mi package.json

  "name": "my world master",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mi primer proyecto de node.js",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "dev":"lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my world master"
  },
  "author": "Josue Andres",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  },
Aun así cuando lo instale me dio error de una ves

Comment: Ese contenido que haz puesto en el comentario (todo tu package.json) deberia ir en tu pregunta, porfavor editala y pon ese codigo, para que toda la comunidad pueda verlo mas facilmente y en la parte adecuada.

Comment: Ya lo pongo, gracias es mi primera vez con todo esto. Seria en el titulo en donde pondria todo el contenido de mi package.json?

Comment: En el contenido de la pregunta, si te fijas hay un boton de editar justo debajo de tu pregunta, en el cual si le das podras editar el contenido de tu pregunta y poner mas para complementarla, porsupuesto no debe ir en el titulo.

Comment: Estas seguro de que ese es todo tu package.json?, a mi se me hace que omitiste algun detalle, si tu hiciste la operacion que te dije el error debe haberse solucionado. en tu caso al parecer copiaste exactamente el mismo json que tenias antes, en vez de haber instalado de manera normal los plugins que requerias.

Comment: Si disculpa no habia borrado el anterior y lo publique. Ya tengo el nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Pues segun puedo ver en tu `JSON` hay unos pocos errores:

```
{
  "name": "my world master",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mi primer proyecto de node.js",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my world master"
  },
  "author": "Josue Andres",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  },
```

El primero es que si te fijas no estas cerrando el `JSON`, es decir te falta una llave de cierre al final `}`, por esa razon falla.

El segundo, es que la ultima propiedad y valor de un `JSON` NO LLEVA COMA, en tu caso la propiedad `devDependencies` es la ultima, pero le pusiste una coma al final si te fijas:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
},//Esta coma genera problemas
```

Para comprobar que esto se soluciona vamos a hacer un `JSON.parse` desde javascript, agregandole `}` al final del `JSON` y ademas quitandole la `,` que sobra al `JSON`:

```js
const package = `{
  "name": "my world master",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mi primer proyecto de node.js",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my world master"
  },
  "author": "Josue Andres",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  }
}`;

const packageJSON = JSON.parse(package);
```

Como vemos ya no nos da errores, por lo tanto hemos arreglado el problema haciendo cambios sumamente pequeños y faciles de seguir.